# 500 internal error while creating restAPI in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I am getting 500 internal error while executing a basic program on the rest API in a jersey project

Student.java

```
package com.api.api;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private String marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

StudentResource.java

```
package com.api.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("student")
public class StudentResource {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Student getStudents()
    {
        System.out.println("called...");
        Student s1=new Student();
        s1.setMarks("19");
        s1.setName("kart");
        s1.setSubject("maths");
        
        System.out.println(s1.getMarks());
        
        return s1;
       // return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";  
    }

}
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b06</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

where I added this dependency additionally

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

this is the output I got

[image]

I suspect there is some issue with the XML bind, because when I return the XML as a string it is working fine but when i convert the object to XML i am getting internal error so please help me solving this

this is my file structure in eclipse
[image]

and also I am not able to see any error logs

[image]

Comment: When you say "I am not able to see any error logs", do you mean that the logs contain no errors, or that you don't know where the logs are created?

Comment: i mean to say that there is no error printed in the console

Comment: have a look in the servlet engine log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Root cause analysis

### `ClassNotFoundException`

Probably, the `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown by the `org.glassfish.hk2.osgiresourcelocator.ServiceLoader#lookupProviderClasses` method.

The `ClassNotFoundException` exception message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

The `ClassNotFoundException` exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:311)
<…>
```

### `JAXBException`

The mentioned above `ClassNotFoundException` exception is caught and rethrown as `JAXBException` by the `javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder#newInstance(java.lang.Class[], java.util.Map, java.lang.String)` method.

The `JAXBException` exception message:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
>
> - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

The `JAXBException` exception stacktrace:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
<…>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
<…>
```

### Root cause

The root cause is described by the `JAXBException` exception message:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

## Solution

Add the JAXB implementation Maven dependency.

For example, this one seems to work fine for the mentioned version of JAXB API:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this i wasted 3 days ,you helped me a lot